# NoSuchMethodError Version.compareTo() when launching Web Preview Server in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, websphere, osgi, websphere-8

Using "Tools for developing and administering WebSphere® Application Server V8.0L (or V8.5). in Eclipse (Kepler), I ań getting a following error message when I want to start the Web Preview Server:

```
CWWKE0005E: The runtime environment could not be launched.
com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.LaunchException: Caught unexpected exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/osgi/framework/Version.compareTo(Lorg/osgi/framework/Version;)I
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.internal.KernelBootstrap.rethrowException(KernelBootstrap.java:412)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.internal.KernelBootstrap.go(KernelBootstrap.java:179)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.Launcher.createPlatform(Launcher.java:131)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:55)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.cmdline.EnvCheck.main(EnvCheck.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/osgi/framework/Version.compareTo(Lorg/osgi/framework/Version;)I
    at org.osgi.framework.VersionRange.isEmpty0(VersionRange.java:332)
    at org.osgi.framework.VersionRange.<init>(VersionRange.java:182)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.provisioning.VersionUtility.<clinit>(VersionUtility.java:28)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:228)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.internal.KernelResolver$ResolverCache.checkEntry(KernelResolver.java:498)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.internal.KernelResolver.<init>(KernelResolver.java:135)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.internal.KernelBootstrap.go(KernelBootstrap.java:122)
    ... 3 more
CWWKE0018E: An exception occurred while launching the runtime environment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/osgi/framework/Version.compareTo(Lorg/osgi/framework/Version;)I
```

What is going on? I understand that something inside the server tries to use an object which does not have the required method. But why? How can I fix it?

Comment: It seems there is a library conflict on your classpath (multiple versions of the OSGi framework). One of them contains the compareTo() method, the other not -- and the latter is found by the runtime environment when you want to start the appserver. Double-check your settings.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. In JRE definition, I had java external directories among Default VM arguments:

```
-Djava.ext.dirs=d:\ws8\java\jre\lib;d:\ws8\java\jre\lib\ext;d:\ws8\lib;d:\ws8\plugins
```

d:\ws8 is the installation directory of my WebSphere 8.0. Apparently, they contain also much osgi stuff.

I knew these settings were there, I needed them in some other cases. But I did not expect they can cause problems in other IBM's software.

(Thanks to rlegendi for a small kick.)